# How to remove SMS messages from the server

Tags: sms, messaging

If I am the sender for using SMS, is there anyway I can remove the message that I have sent to the receiver? Perhaps programmatically?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As with e-mail, once sent, it's sent. You can't reach into someone's phone and revoke a message.